# How to run Amazon polly on Firebase Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, amazon-polly

I got working code on local NodeJs server, then I tried to run same code on Firebase Function and failed.

Here is my code split into 2 files:

// index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const polly = require("./polly");


exports.pollySynth = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
  return polly.speak()
});
```

// polly.js

```
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");


// Create an Polly client
const Polly = new AWS.Polly({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: "my-region",
  accessKeyId: "keyId,
  secretAccessKey: "access key",
});

// Params
const params = {
  Text: "Hello world. This is the word of speech!",
  OutputFormat: "json",
};

// prettier-ignore
const synthSpeech = function() {
  Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      return err;
    } else if (res && res.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
      return res.AudioStream;
    }
  });
};

module.exports = {speak: synthSpeech};
```

When trying to deploy this function, I'm getting this error:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: pollySynth(us-central1)
```

I'm not pro coder, so maybe it's just some dumb error in my code.. Please help me :)

Comment: Please include the rest of the error message as it provides details of what went wrong.

Comment: @samthecodingman this is all I get.. At console I found just this: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.

Comment: Have you checked the logs mentioned?

Comment: @samthecodingman there are no logs, I need to write some logging function to get it.

Comment: @samthecodingman 

Finally got log by running this command: 

"firebase functions:log --only pollySynth"

2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: Require stack:
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: - /workspace/polly.js
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: - /workspace/index.js
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth: - /layers/google.nodejs.

Comment: Can't find how to install 'aws-sdk'. Answers from documentation and stackoverflow not working... 

Tried: npm install aws-sdk --save
Added "aws-sdk": "^2.969.0" to "package.json", nothing works(

Still the same error.

Comment: Please edit in that log to your question (rather than leave it as a comment) and also edit in your `package.json` file that is in you `functions` directory.

Comment: Also for future reference, you can access your Functions logs from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/functions/logs) in addition to the CLI tool you used.

Comment: @samthecodingman thank you for assistance. What I want to say that I didn't found any detailed logs in Firebase Console. All it said - that I just have some error in my function.

Answer (score 1):

That took around half day to solve this issue. The root of the problem was that for some reason, firebase didn't provide detailed error logs. It just said that there is some error in the code.

Only running this command through the command line helped me to understand what's wrong:

```
firebase functions:log --only pollySynth
```

I found that command only at StackOverflow, and official documentation didn't mention it.

Log looked this way:

```
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
2021-08-20T12:04:51.823Z ? speechSynth:
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
```

Now I understand that problem is that npm modules was not installed. It worked locally with an emulator, but deploy was throwing an error

I tried to install aws sdk using commands like this again and again. Tried to add module into package.json manually as well, but nothing worked...

```
npm install aws-sdk
npm install --save
```

Then I looked into "node_modules" folder inside the "functions" folder and didn't find that package!

Then I looked at the folder structure installed by default:

```
 - root
   - functions
     - node modules
   - public
```

It seems like the terminal is running the command on the root folder, and "node_modules" is placed inside the "functions" folder.

So I opened the terminal, moved to the "functions" folder, and installed aws sdk.

```
cd functions
npm install aws-sdk
```

And successfully deployed the function!

The next problem was that the function return null. I needed to use a promise to wait for aws server response.

And that code worked for me:

```
const createSpeech = function() {
  return Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params)
    .promise()
    .then((audio) => {
      if (audio.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
        return audio.AudioStream;
      } else {
        throw new Error("AudioStream is not a Buffer.");
      }
    });
};
```

Now everything works correctly, and I can move to the next steps.